# is there a single process/term to describe dissipation and amplification of a signal?

Tags: signal-analysis, modulation

I am writing a paper, and the topic is about a signal that could be either amplified or dissipated while traveling through a medium. Since I don't wanna write everywhere "amplified or dissipated ", e.g. "the plot shows the signal amplification or dissipation", is there a single word I could use for both? Maybe amplitude modulation? I don't think it is correct cause there is not a modulating low frequency signal.

Comment: I would try to use the term "gain". In communications, "gain" is understood to be potentially smaller than one. You can refer to the "gain of the medium" rather than the "signal amplification".

Comment: i see. Problem is that I am not talking about communications but water waves signals. I never heard gain in a water waves context. Any other term that could be used for general contexts?

Comment: That subject sure sounds interesting, but I know nothing about it. How about "change in amplitude"?

Comment: Any signal.  Any medium.  "Gain" applies.

Comment: Why is "gain" not a synonym of "amplification"? Which are the differences?